# Converting a date format in sybase

Tags: sybase, isql

I need to convert May 8 2014 to this format 08/05/2014.

I tried using:

```
convert(char(12),"May 8 2014",103)
```

but it did not work.

Kindly suggest a workaround.

Comment: *but it did not work* can you be more specific? What didn't work exactly, etc.

Comment: Also beware of using DD/MM/YYYY for a date format as can easily come unstuck with US folks assuming its MM/DD/YYYY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to convert the string to datetime, and than you should convert it to char as below:

```
select convert(char(12),cast("May 8 2014" as datetime) ,103)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another implementation of same approach , i.e., first convert to datetime:

select convert(char(12),convert(datetime,"May 8 2014") ,103)